# Creating a list that dynamically expands when a request is made C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a website where, when the user logs in he gets an index view of a number of objects, this list contains at this moment a constant of 10 objects that is loaded from my database. I want to be able to give the user the option to then press a button further down that loads another 10 objects that adds on to the list so the user now has 20 objects on his index page. I've been looking into Lazy Load but i don't think this is what i'm looking for.

Or is there a way for me to put a row index in my linq query and then pick up the rest of the rows where i left off?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are looking for 'pagination'.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485531/ASP-NET-Pagination

Comment: Using linq you can use .Skip(10) and .Take(10) for next 10 rows

Comment: yes i am using the .Take(10) but then if i want to take the next 10 rows it just takes the same 10 rows again and i still want to keep the last 10 i got in the previous request

Comment: Add .Skip(10) before the Take

Comment: You clearly have to "save" the 10 of the Skip somewhere, so that the first time it's Skip(0).Take(10), the second time it's Skip(10).Take(10) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
var objectsToShow = allObjectsCollection.Skip(10).Take(10);
```